# Generate Entity Framework code without generating EDMX diagram

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-generation, edmx

I currently generate XML from my [single source of truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth) and save it as an Entity Framework EDMX file and then use the `EntityClassGenerator` object to create the classes from the diagram. Is there a way to generate the classes without having to create the XML file first?

Comment: Can you create classes based on your SSOT?

Comment: If you mean the classes in the designer file that EF creates, yes but I'd rather let EF generate them for me. I have an object hierarchy where each object represents a node in the EDMX. I build up the hierarchy using the meta data in my SSOT and then call a "render" method on each object that uses an XmlTextWriter to create the EDMX. I guess I was hoping to cut out that whole step and just use my meta data to build up an object hierarchy using EF objects and then have them generate the designer classes - bypassing the creation of the EDMX all together. Probably not possible, but I was hoping.

Comment: If you can generate classes directly you can give up with EDMX and generate POCOs, Code first mapping and DbContext classes instead.

Comment: You should add this as an answer. Sounds like just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard back from Ladislav Mrnka, so I'll put his comment here as an answer. Using the Entity Framework's new [Code-First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx), I can have a code-centric development workflow where my generator will create POCOs and a custom DbContext, then my database will be generated from the POCOs using convention instead of configuration. No need for an EDMX at all!

Here's a good explanation of it: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx

Answer (score 0):

EF needs the metadata from the EDMX at runtime. Even if you could use CodeModel or something to generate the entity classes, they would be useless to the EF runtime without the metadata describing the storage model, mapping etc.

Answer (score 0):

Fabio Scopel has a webcast on youTube where he shows this Beta Tool (back then) called Entity Framework Reverse Engineer.

Check the link [Entity Framework 5.0 - Code First Reverse Engineering existing DataBase](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhJaEVQMxJ4)

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.